# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openSPI'

Tags: python, nfc, raspberry-pi2, rfid, spi

I am a beginner with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I am trying to connect an NFC card reader to RPi. 
I watched the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGs048l6kbQ&list=PLP7qPet500dcE-zP_-EVEisi7N1Lh4Ekk&index=1

I went successfully through videos 1-5.

In the 6. video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jncDxNI3AGk&index=6&list=PLP7qPet500dcE-zP_-EVEisi7N1Lh4Ekk) I typed the command `sudo python read.py`, and it showed me the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/MFRC522-python $ sudo python read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "read.py", line 5, in <module>
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()
File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 107, in __init__
spi.openSPI(speed=spd)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openSPI'
```

I couldn't find anything on the Internet, what can be a solution to my error. 
Could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [spi-PY package](https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py) using `python setup.py build && python setup.py install` (use sudo if needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo pip uninstall spi
```

clone SPI-Py  package from https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git and call python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same Problem... 
You got to use [virtual-env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (recommended by community).

Reinstalling all the dependencies inlcuding the SPI Module in an active virtual-environment did the trick for me.

The Doc´s: [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).